# Using ionic in visual studio

Tags: ionic-framework

I am currently developing a mobile app using ionic..but i was wondering of its possible to develop an ionic app using visual studio community 2015.I have attempted coding in visual studio using ionic in VS,but it seems like the js scripts used in regular web apps are not recognized by ionic.And i dont like Telerik and Kendo UI because the app behaves in a sticky manner.I am trying to develop a cross platform app that behaves and looks as native as possible..Please guide me on how to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio is one of the best ways to developer hybrid mobile apps with Ionic. Frankly I prefer to use Visual Studio Code. It's a lightweight code editor that's fast and optimized for ASP.NET and Node.js development.

You can find help here:

http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-templates-for-visual-studio/

http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/

http://dustinewers.com/how-to-ionic-in-visual-studio/

Or try to better explain your problem so we can help.

Comment: My Main issue is that i cant use other css and js scripts from other webapp template sources when developing with ionic.I am basicaly failing to customize my app to respond to css animations,boostrap and other css and js scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try WebStorm it is the best one for developing cross platform.
you can integrate it with any plugin. it is full of tools for javaScript technologies with built in terminal.